# Is there any way to convert this string to hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
{"table_no"=>nil, "name"=>"Kelly Shaye Gan", "account_id"=>1}
```

I mean I'm sure there is; just spent couple of hours trying to figure it out. I think the answer lies here: [Most efficient way to map a specific string into a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333995/most-efficient-way-to-map-a-specific-string-into-a-hash-in-ruby), but I'm not an expert in regex, so I'm not sure which expression to plug into the scan.

Comment: I think the question that needs to be asked is: why do you have that string in the first place? Solutions that `eval` are usually indicative of a design flaw further up the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're sure the input is always safe, you can eval it:

`the_hash = eval(the_string)`

Comment: thanks i actually tried taht already and i end up getting a syntax error. would my example above work for you?

Comment: yes, it worked for me. `the_string = '{"table_no"=>nil, "name"=>"Kelly Shaye Gan", "account_id"=>1}'`